# How do I remotely track a missing persons Android with GPS

Tags: remote-control, geolocation, gps-tracking

I have a family member missing over a week now. How do I remotely track the missing person on their Android and get a GPS location?

I need to use my desktop computer to do the tracking.

Comment: you might need to install an app, which will be difficult :(  Sorry about the missing relative.

Comment: Do you have access to a Google account that's logged into the phone?

Comment: The purpose of this site is to allow questions and answers to be available for other people, including in the future. Although your personal problem may be resolved, it's best to leave your question for others to read, so I am reverting your question. Alternately, you can delete your question entirely.

Answer (score 4):

If you have access to the Google account on the phone, you can use [Google's Android Device Manager](https://www.google.com/android/devicemanager) to locate the device. [This requires the phone to be powered on with location services enabled](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/6160491?hl=en). This will notify the phone as well.

If you do not have access to the Google account, you need a preinstalled tracking application, like [Google+](https://support.google.com/plus/answer/2998354?hl=en). Some more examples of preinstalled options:
https://www.cnet.com/news/location-tracking-apps/
http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-share-your-location-and-GPS-coordinates-using-your-smartphone_id50312

If you don't have either of these, then you can't use GPS to locate the phone; you need to have the phone service provider locate the phone (provided it's on). This is not a service normally provided to the general public. Get help from law enforcement, a private investigator, or a skip tracer.